# fixed range y axis scale in achartengine

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I am making line chart using achartengine. I draw real time graph and values are updating with interval of 10 second. my Y axis is changing the scale which I do not want as my value will always from 10 to 180 so I want to have fixed y axis always. I am trying to make it work using this

```
renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 1);
renderer.setYAxisMax(180, 1);
```

In addition I want to reduce the space of my x -axis and screen bottom and border too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AchartEngine provides you api to set the range for Y axis and it is correct just you have to use it like this,

```
 renderer.setYAxisMin(-125, 1);
 renderer.setYAxisMax(-10, 1);
```

It is minor issue but takes time to recognize, I spent 15-30 mins to figure it out.
I hope I am not late